# I need help to solve a nested FORM problem

Tags: php, html, forms, post, submit

Having a table generated from MySQL datas, each row has a field containing multiple forms.

I need to put a checkbox on the first field of each row, containing the unique ID, and later I need to pass the multiple checkbox values by POST with a button located outside the table.

How do I obtain that, when nested forms cannot be done?

Here's my code:

```
    <!-- This button needs to be outside of the table -->
    <button type="submit" form="selected_checkboxes">Send checked boxes</button>

    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <!-- If I put the form there, for the selected checkbox, it won't work, because the other forms
    are nested inside the table -->
    <form action="page.php" method="POST" name="selected_checkboxes">  <!-- THIS WON'T WORK -->

    <?php
    $db = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = ? ORDER BY id DESC');
    $db->bind_param('i', $name);
    if (!$db->execute()) die('Error while fetching accounts: '. $conn->error);
    $res = $db->get_result();
    while ($data = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $data['id'];
        $name = $data['name'];
        echo '<tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="'.$id.'"></td>
        <td>'.$name.'</td>
        <td>
            <form action="page.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" /><button type="submit" name="action1">Send</button></form>
            <form action="page.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" /><button type="submit" name="action2">Archive</button></form>
        </td>
        </tr>
    }
    ?>
    
    </form>  <!-- TO CLOSE THE NOT WORKING FORM -->
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($$conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: @Dharman I appreciate it, but it's a personal project, so I don't really look at that, but thanks

Comment: Since they all go to the same place, just use the outer form and test for the individual actions ($action1, $action2)

Comment: Why? Why would you ignore my advice to make your code simpler and better? If you are only learning PHP then please start by learning the easiest solutions. Don't overcomplicate it.

Comment: @Dharman it's not about make it simpler or better, since it's personal project, nobody will ever even see it

Comment: @TimMorton Them goes to same place, but, each row has different IDs and datas that has to be transferred through the Action column, that is the one giving me struggle

Comment: working on an answer, but I see you already accepted an answer.  If you want to consider a different route, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td>
    <form action="page.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" />
    <button type="submit" name="action1">Send</button>
    </form>
    <form action="page.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" />
    <button type="submit" name="action2">Archive</button>
    </form>
    </td>
```

in this section I would modify it with hotlinks instead of forms and make diffrent handling page, for example:

```
echo "<td><a href='page2.php?action=send&id=".$id."'>Send</a> ";
echo "<a href='page2.php?action=archive&id=".$id."'>Send</a></td>";
```

and the page2.php would operate on $_GET["action"] and $_GET["id"] like replaced mini-form.

then your form from the begining (with checkboxes, that you stated that doesn't work) will be the only one and work :)
this will be ok only if you gave access to verified user.

hope this will push you foreward.

:)

Comment: This actually helps me a lot, I haven't thought about converting the nested forms into GET links. Thanks!

Comment: glad that I pushed it foreward a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are actually manipulating the data and not simply requesting a view, POST is the appropriate verb to use.

You can simply index the submit buttons with the id of the selected item.  I have put your script into a standard format of working with potential user input (assuming this script is page.php) and then displaying the form:

```
<?php
// get $conn and other config

if(!empty($_POST['selected_checkboxes']) {
    // iterate through $_POST['id_list']
    header(location: '/page/to/show/on/completion');
    exit;
}

if(!empty($_POST['send']) {
    $arr = (array)$_POST['send'];
    $id = array_keys($arr)[0];
    // do what you need to do with the id
    header(location: '/page/to/show/on/completion');
    exit;
}

if(!empty($_POST['archive']) {
    $arr = (array)$_POST['archive'];
    $id = array_keys($arr)[0];
    // do what you need to do with the id
    header(location: '/page/to/show/on/completion');
    exit;
}
$db = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = ? ORDER BY id DESC');
$db->bind_param('i', $name);
$accountList = $db->get_result();
?>
<html>
...
<form action="page.php" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="selected_checkboxes">Send checked boxes</button>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php while($data = $accountList->fetch_assoc()): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="id_list[]" value="<?= $data['id'] ?>"></td>
                <td><?= $data['name'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" name="send[<?= $data['id'] ?>]">Send</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="archive[<?= $data['id'] ?>]">Archive</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```